# How to replace glut32.dll library with freeglut.dll in Delphi XE easily (program stops suddenly)

Tags: delphi, 32bit-64bit, glut, freeglut

I have the following issue.
I'm using Glut openGL for drawing certain elements in my application written in Delphi. The library file I'm using is called **glut32.dll** (placed where the **EXE** file is standing)
Now I decided to compile my app in 64-bit as other libraries it is using are going to be updated only for 64-bit. All fine, but the one thing that stops me is the **glut32.dll** (it is 32-bit). As the Glut project is not supported for many years already I found the ***freeglut*** alternative which claim to be replacement for the original Glut: https://freeglut.sourceforge.net/, and downloaded the **freeglut.dll** from here: [www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/](https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/) for MSVC.

As I looked at the **.h** header files it seems more or less the same as my code translation is in the *.pas files.
So I tried to just load the *freeglut.dll* instead of *glut32.dll* (*dll* is set to the correct dll name in the function below)

```delphi
    procedure LoadGlut(const dll: String);
    begin
    
      FreeGlut;
    
      hDLL := LoadLibrary(PChar(dll));
      if hDLL = 0 then raise Exception.Create('Could not load Glut from ' + dll);
    
      @glutInit := GetProcAddress(hDLL, 'glutInit');
      @glutInitDisplayMode := GetProcAddress(hDLL, 'glutInitDisplayMode');
      @glutCreateWindow := GetProcAddress(hDLL, 'glutCreateWindow');
      @glutCreateSubWindow := GetProcAddress(hDLL, 'glutCreateSubWindow');
      @glutDestroyWindow := GetProcAddress(hDLL, 'glutDestroyWindow');
      @glutPostRedisplay := GetProcAddress(hDLL, 'glutPostRedisplay');
      ...
```

It is loading with no errors and so on, also the procedures in it, but when the application start and reach a point to use one of these functions it just stop the debugger with no error message (like pressing Ctrl+F2).

```delphi
    procedure DrawArrow(P1, P2: TRPoint; Color: TRGBAColor);
    var
      R : Real;
    begin
      DrawLine(P1, P2, Color);
      glColor4fv(@Color[0]);
      glPushMatrix;
        SetZAxis(P2, P1);
        R := VectorModulus(VectorDifference(P1,P2));
        glTranslated(0, 0, R);
        SetSymbolScale;
          glTranslated(0, 0, -ARROW_L);
          glutSolidCone(ARROW_W/2, ARROW_L, SOLID_SLICES, SOLID_STACKS);
        glPopMatrix;
      glPopMatrix;
    end;
```

The debugger shut itself at glutSolidCone(ARROW_W/2, ARROW_L, SOLID_SLICES, SOLID_STACKS); This function is defined in freeglut as well.

**EDIT:** If I call other simple function like *glutInitDisplayMode* it doesn't stop, so it seems that the library is correctly loaded. But it still keeps shutting down at *glutSolidCone* or other drawing functions.

I don't have much experience of using these header files and *dll* that comes with it, but my Delphi code should be a good translation in this case? Or not? I don't know how to debug this.
What is the way to adapt my code in order to fit **freeglut** in it. It should be something small I think as most of the things should be the same.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that just replacing ***glut32.dll*** with ***freeglut.dll*** won't do the job properly as I guess functions inside differs a bit (or simply renaming *freeglut.dll* --> *glut32.dll* also fails). However I found a workaround published by NVIDIA: [NVIDIA Cg Toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cg-toolkit)

It is not supported since 2013, but when installed it brings the ***dll*** version of *glut32* both for 32-bit and 64-bit development. Quickly try it and it seems to work and cover what I have as definition in Glut.pas.

So if you need 64-bit version and replacement of ***glut32.dll*** it can be downloaded from there.

Meanwhile if somebody convert the freeglut headers (.h) to Delphi code it would be great as at the end the *Freeglut* projecy is still maintained, up-to-date and add some more useful functions in addition to the original Glut. This conversion is still beyond my knowledge.